# MDB Message consumer delay

Tags: jboss, jms, message-driven-bean, hornetq

Is there any option in hornetq to set message consumer delay. if so kindly help with an example.
Our Req: We need MDB to read message with a constant 2 min delay.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the usual use-case for MDBs. Are you sure you need an MBD? Have you thought about Topic queues?

Or can you describe the business reasons for requiring a delay?

Comment: we need it for EDI processing, when an EDI request comes in, the messages related to that edi should be processed and sent after 2 min.

Answer (score 0):

OK - then I think you should just get the message, use a

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html

and use that with a scheduler service like Quartz or the new timer-stuff in EJB3.1.

Best,
Anders

Answer (score 0):

One option is to put a JMS header that has the time you want to process the message at. For example, 2 minute from when you create the message.  Then, your reader can have a time based selector that only selects messages where that header is > the current time.